# Stretch Between 2 Vector3 Unity UI

Tags: unity-game-engine

[image: I am trying to stretch a UnityEngine.UI image between 2 vectors]

The code I'm using is

```
public void Strech(GameObject sprite, Vector3 initialPosition, Vector3 finalPosition)
{
    Vector3 centerPos = (initialPosition + finalPosition) / 2f;

    sprite.transform.position = centerPos;

    Vector3 direction = finalPosition - initialPosition;
    direction = Vector3.Normalize(direction);
    sprite.transform.right = direction;

    distance = Vector3.Distance(initialPosition, finalPosition);

    Debug.DrawLine(initialPosition, finalPosition);

    sprite.GetComponent<RectTransform>().sizeDelta = new Vector3(distance, 40f);
}
```

I can't seem to figure out why the image won't tile to or from either centers of the UI objects.

What am I doing wrong? I call the Stretch function in the Update loop.
The red line itself is a UnityEngine.UI Image type.

I want the image to tile as shown by the Debug.DrawLine

Edit 1: Here's how the rect is being displayed

[image: Stretch()]

Comment: what is your image type in inspector?

Comment: My image type is tiled

Comment: does your image's rect transform stretched? can you click on your image and show result of your rect?

Comment: Added a screenshot as an edit to my original post.

Comment: is distance between two points is 136? i mean image rect (use rect tool in editor) is correct or its problems with calculations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it!
I had to multiply a scalefactor, because the Canvas was using a Canvas Scaler with reference resolution of 1280 x 720